# Creating users, and grants

Tags: tapkey

I'm creating users and issuing grants to them. I have a limitation with token exchange since these users belong to a different ownerAccount.

I'm doing something similar to what is described here https://developers.tapkey.io/mobile/embedded/getting_started/#creating-a-user but on a server and not mobile.
My challenge is that the ownerAccount to which the user should be created (the one which has the lock for which I want to make grants is different from my account(which has the identity provider) so I get an error, is it possible to create users using `authorization code` as a mode of authentication?

```
try {
  const user = await axios.put(
    `${this.baseUrl}/owners/${this.ownerAccountId}/identityproviders/${this.provider}/users`,
    {
      'ipUserId': details.userId
    },
    {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
      }
    }
  )
  // create a new contact for the user created above
  const contact = await this.createContactForUser(token, user.data.ipUserId)
  // create grant for contact created above
  await this.createGrantForContact(token, contact.id, details.lockId)
  return user.data.ipUserId
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understood from previous questions, you are using `authorization code`
flow and not `token exchange`. In that case no identity provider is involved as you are using Tapkey credentials directly.

If you have retrieved an `access token` from `authorization code` flow, then you use this one to create contacts and grants with **default** (= tapkey) **identity provider**.

Contact or smartphone user works as a connector between *owner account* and an actual *user*, identified by an email. Grants are then created for the contact and not the user directly.

For instance, if you create a contact for *alvin@somedomain.com* and assign the grant to him, it doesn't matter if the user with such an email already exists. He **will receive an email** about grants being assigned to him and it's up to the user to register the Tapkey account or not.

So in your case, you should create a contact with required identifier (email address)
https://developers.tapkey.io/openapi/tapkey_management_api_v1/#/Contacts/Contacts_Put

and then create grants for this contact
https://developers.tapkey.io/openapi/tapkey_management_api_v1/#/Grants/Grants_Put